# Drop Shadow using sencha touch

Tags: sencha-charts

As per my requirements, I need drop shadow in sencha charts.

Is it possible to add a drop shadow to sencha charts?

Thanks,
Nag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `getShadowOptions`in `touchcharts-debug.js`. With that i can able to change shadow options like shadow width, shadow color and blurness. but not able to bring drop shadow.

```
getShadowOptions: function(force) {
    return {
        shadowOffsetX: 3,

        shadowOffsetY: Ext.is.Android ? -2 : 2,
        shadowBlur: 3,
    shadowColor: '#000000'
    };
},
```